# Android WebView error - Sandboxing is not allowed - but works fine on Chrome

Tags: webview, android-webview, chromium

There are a few live streaming sites that work on Chrome for Android just fine but when you use them with Android System WebView browsers you get an error that says "Sandboxing is not allowed". It seems like the sites are trying to do something inside an iFrame that they don't have access to but somehow on Chrome they do.

Is there some setting I can change on the WebView to allow this?

Comment: what is your android version?

Comment: I've seen this on 5+ and I've tested it repeatedly on 9. So it affects both the Android System WebView and the Chrome WebView.